# Replace function symbols with predicate symbols in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I have seen that if we take a first order language that contains some functional symbols $f_1, \dots f_n$, then we can replace those functional symbols by $n$ new predicate symbols that have bigger arity.For example, if we have $f(x,y) = z$, we would replace it with $F(x,y,z)$. Is there a way to prove that those languages are equivalent?

If we have a language $L$ with only one function symbol ($f/1$) (no predicates or constants), we want to create another language $L'$ with only one predicate symbol ($F/2$), such that if $\phi$ is a sentence and $M$ is a model of language $L$ $M \models \phi \iff \bar{M} \models \bar{\phi}$, where $\bar{M}$ is a model for $L'$ and $\bar{\phi}$ is the new sentence $\in L'$

Comment: See [Functional predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_predicate)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you be little more precise on how to proceed with the proof so i can show that for every sentence in a structure with functional symbols, there is an equivalent sentence with only predicate symbols?

Comment: "Is there a way to prove that those languages are equivalent?" Not unless you define what it means for two languages to be equivalent.

Comment: I edited my question!

Comment: You haven't defined your "translations" $\varphi\leadsto\overline{\varphi}$ and $M\leadsto\overline{M}$, but I presume you mean the obvious relationalizations, right? You should write out at least the definition of $\overline{\varphi}$ in terms of $\varphi$ explicitly; unlike $M\leadsto\overline{M}$ it's more subtle than one might first expect. As to the proof that $M\models\varphi$ iff $\overline{M}\models\overline{\varphi}$, it's a standard argument by **induction on formula complexity**; if you haven't seen such an argument before, it would be a good idea to look at an easier example first.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, i mean the obvious relationalizations. I have seen arguments using induction on formula complexity. But we are interested in sentences (formulas with no free variables), so i am a bit confused about the induction itself. So any hint would be appreciated

Comment: @Oeto_101 This is a situation where we need to "strengthen the induction:" even when we just want to prove a result about sentences, we may nonetheless have to go **through** formulas, or sentences-with-parameters if you prefer *(to be fair I usually do, but many don't)*. One way to phrase the claim you prove by induction is: "for every $L$-structure $M$, every $L$-formula $\varphi$, and every variable assignment $\nu$ of elements of $M$ to free variables in $\varphi$, we have $M\models_\nu\varphi$ iff $\overline{M}\models_\nu\overline{\varphi}$." (cont'd)

Comment: If you prefer to talk about sentences with parameters, the claim is instead: "for every $L$-structure $M$ and every $L$-formula-with-parameters-from-$M$ $\varphi$, we have $M\models\varphi$ iff $\overline{M}\models\overline{\varphi}$." The proof will be by induction on the complexity of $\varphi$; the importance of considering formulas and variable assignments, or sentences with parameters if you prefer, will become clear when tackle the quantifier induction step.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ok, i got your point and i have proven almost everything according to complexity of $\phi$. The only issue that i have, is actually proving the base case in which i consider atomic formulas. The problem is that i cannot prove my statement for $f(t_1, \dots, t_n)$, where $t_1, \dots t_n$ are terms and $f$  is a function symbol. Actually, this is the only case in which $\bar{M}$ is differentiated from $M$.Any workaround for this one?

Comment: @Oeto_101 What do you mean "I cannot prove my statement for $f(t_1,...,t_n)$"? The expression $f(t_1,...,t_n)$ is a *term*, not a formula. The base case for the induction is the atomic formulas. Try the following: supposing you have a unary function symbol $f$ in $L$ and elements $a,b\in M$ with $M\models f(a)=b$, do you see how to show that $\overline{M}\models \overline{f(a)=b}$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I stuck at this point because i start from $M \models f(a) = b$ and by applying Tarski's definition of truth, i am trying to reach to $M'$, but without being able to do.So i really have no clue how to prove what you asked

Comment: @Oeto_101 OK, what's $\overline{f(a)=b}$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It's the following relationship: $\{(a,b) | M \models f(a) = b \}$

Comment: @Oeto_101 No, it's not. That's the *relation corresponding to $f$*. I'm talking about the *translation of the $L$-formula* $f(a)=b$ into $L'$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  $\exists a \exists b \bar{f}(a,b)$, where $\bar{f}$ is the old function symbol from $L$ that became a predicate symbol in $L'$

Comment: @Oeto_101 No, remember $a$ and $b$ are *specific elements* from $M$ (if you're doing the sentences-with-parameters version). So $\overline{f(a)=b}$ needs to be a *sentence-with-parameters* in $L'$. (If you're doing the formulas version instead, we should be talking about the formula $f(x)=y$; this is a formula with two free variables, so its translation should also be a formula with two free variables.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am doing the formulas version as it seems more understandable for me.  I will try to explain my process. $f$ is a function symbol that belongs to $L$. I want to replace functions symbols from $L$ with predicate symbols in L'. As far as $f$ has arity of 1, i will introduce a predicate symbol $\bar{f}$ in $L'$ with arity 2 and if i see $f(x) = y$, i will replace it with $\bar{f}(x,y)$

Comment: OK, good. So in fact you've answered my question: the $L'$-formula you assign to the $L$-formula $f(x)=y$ is just $\overline{f}(x,y)$. Full stop. The next issue is to consider nested function symbols: what $L'$-formula does $f(f(x))=y$ translate to? (Here you'll have a choice of two options to make; both options will work, but the existence of such a choice may feel weird so I just want to warn about it.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber $\exists z (\bar{f}(x,z) \land \bar{f}(z,y)$, i guess

Comment: @Oeto_101 Yes, that's exactly right. Now things get really messy when look at formulas with more complicated terms, like $$g(f(x), f(f(y)))=h(y,z,f(x))$$ or similar, but the basic idea of the translation $\varphi\leadsto\overline{\varphi}$ should now be clear: we introduce "auxiliary variables" as necessary to handle nesting in terms. (Incidentally, the choice I referred to above was the following: while you do need to introduce a new variable via a quantifier, either $\exists$ or $\forall$ would work.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Great. I think i have the idea on my mind now about translating formulas. But how do i show that $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are logically equivalent under the same function $v$ that assigns values to $\phi, \phi'$ variables?

Comment: @Oeto_101 Well, that's going to be by induction on complexity, with the atomic case being the nasty one because of complicated "nesting" of terms. Can you see how to prove it for e.g. $f(f(x))=y$ versus $\overline{f(f(x))=y}$? By your previous comment, this amounts to showing that for every variable assignment $\nu:\{x,y\}\rightarrow M$ we have $$M\models_\nu f(f(x))=y$$ iff $$\overline{M}\models_\nu\exists z(\overline{f}(x,z)\wedge\overline{f}(z,y)).$$

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am trying to apply Tarski's definition of Truth, but i am stuck at the point where i cannot pass from my initial structure $M$ to my new structure $M'$. I have: $M \models_{v} f(f(x)) = y \iff v[f(f(x))] = v(y) \iff f(f(v(x)) = v(y)$. From there i don't know how to proceed

Comment: For brevity let $a=\nu(x)$ and $b=\nu(y)$, and furthermore let $c=f(a)$ (this corresponds to the "auxiliary" variable $z$). We have $f(c)=b$, so $\overline{f}(c,b)$ holds in $\overline{M}$; meanwhile, by definition $\overline{f}(a,c)$ holds in $\overline{M}$ as well. Now do you see why $\exists z(\overline{f}(a,z)\wedge\overline{f}(z,b))$ holds in $\overline{M}$? What does that imply about the status of $M\models_\nu\exists z(\overline{f}(x,z)\wedge\overline{f}(z,y))$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes!!! So all i have to do now, is to make an iduction based on level of application of $f$ $f(....f(x).....)...) = $y. Am i thinking it right?